# -flatten option use in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

My program uses ImageMagick to convert a multipage tiff to pdf.

*convert.exe "C:\multipage_tiff_example.tif"  -flatten "pdf:C:\cache\multipage_tiff_example-636946171.pdf"*

**Issue**

If I use -flatten in the above command for **multipage tiff** files, it only renders the *first page* of the tiff to pdf.

And removing -flatten, gives the correct **PDF** rendition for all the pages.

**My doubt**

I read about the -flatten option [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#layers) as well. But I am unable to understand why it only gives a single page in the rendition.

Comment: What is your IM version?  A similar command works fine for me in IM 6.9.8.6 Q16 Mac OSX.  Can you post a link to your tif file? Is it two pages or two layers? Does this work:  convert.exe "C:\multipage_tiff_example.tif[0--1]" -flatten "pdf:C:\cache\multipage_tiff_example-636946171.pdf".  Does your tiff have transparency?

Comment: Its a 2 page @fmw42

Comment: Do you want a one page PDF or a two page PDF?  If the latter, then remove the -flatten. If the former, then my command above in my previous comment worked fine. So if that does not work for you, then post your 2-page tiff or a link to it, so we can test with it. Perhaps your version of ImageMagick is too old and needs to be updated?

Comment: I wanted a 2 page and it worked. The usage of -flatten was not clear from the wiki, as I am a newbie. But thanks a lot for the clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what "-flatten" does.  It takes a sequence of images, composes them one at a time against the previous image(s), taking transparency into account, resulting in a single opaque composite image.

If you wanted a series of images to be output, each composed against the preceding image(s), then use the "-coalesce" option instead.